# how to save a variable with the current data saved in an interval updating state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I am builidng a typicall stopwatch/clock app in [here](https://github.com/elisasoto/pt-abril-2021-crono-clock-project-react).

The issue: When clicking `Pause` Button then `Split` Button (which prints the elapsed time) and then start back, both the stopwatch and the printed time restart. That is because I am saving the Crono time in the `handleClickSplit` function. Any ideas on the best way to save that **current paused time** to prevent the bug?

This is the image

[image]

This is my code:

```js
export default function Home({ enableCrono }) {
  const [cronoTime, setCronoTime] = useState({ h: 0, m: 0, s: 0, ms: 0 });
  const [printTime, setPrintTime] = useState([]);
  const [interv, setInterv] = useState();
  const [status, setStatus] = useState(0);
  // 0 => not running
  // 1 => start
  // 2 => pause
  // 3 => stop

  const start = () => {
    if (cronoTime.m === 60) {
      cronoTime.h++;
      cronoTime.m = 0;
    }
    if (cronoTime.s === 60) {
      cronoTime.m++;
      cronoTime.s = 0;
    }
    if (cronoTime.ms === 100) {
      cronoTime.s++;
      cronoTime.ms = 0;
    }
    cronoTime.ms++;
    return setCronoTime({
      ms: cronoTime.ms,
      s: cronoTime.s,
      m: cronoTime.m,
      h: cronoTime.h,
    });
  };

  const handleClickStart = () => {
    start();
    setStatus(1);
    setInterv(setInterval(start, 10));
  };
  const handleClickStop = () => {
    clearInterval(interv);
    setStatus(3);
  };
  const handleClickPause = () => {
    clearInterval(interv);
    setStatus(2);
  };

  const handleClickClear = () => {
    clearInterval(interv);
    setStatus(0);
    setCronoTime({ h: 0, m: 0, s: 0, ms: 0 });
    setPrintTime([]);
  };

  const handleClickSplit = () => {
    setPrintTime((prevtime) => [...prevtime, cronoTime]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're saving in your `printTime` array a reference to the very same `cronoTime` object. Just save a new object, so that changes on `cronoTime` do not propagate to the object in `printTime`:

```
setPrintTime((prevtime) => [...prevtime, {...cronoTime}]);
```

Comment: brilliant! thank you so much for the clear explanation.